# Removing CSS Class Attribute From Tag in a Custom Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

Greetings!

I've created a custom button class to render the following:

```
<span class="btnOrange">
    <input type="submit" id="ctl00_MainContent_m_GoBack" value="Back" name="ctl00$MainContent$m_GoBack"/>
</span>
```

However, it renders like this instead (note the extraneous "class" attribute in the INPUT tag):

```
<span class="btnOrange">
    <input type="submit" class="btnOrange" id="ctl00_MainContent_m_GoBack" value="Back" name="ctl00$MainContent$m_GoBack"/>
</span>
```

My custom button class looks like this:

```
[ToolboxData(@"<{0}:MyButton runat=server></{0}:MyButton>")]
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
       writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, this.CssClass);   
       writer.RenderBeginTag("span");
       base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
    }

    public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
       writer.RenderEndTag();
       base.RenderEndTag(writer);
    }
}
```

Since I only need to set the class attribute for the SPAN tag, is it possible to not include or "blank out" the class attribute for the INPUT tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
private string _heldCssClass = null;
public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
   writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, this.CssClass);   
   writer.RenderBeginTag("span");
   _heldCssClass = this.CssClass;
   this.CssClass = String.Empty;
   base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
}

public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
   writer.RenderEndTag();
   base.RenderEndTag(writer);
   this.CssClass = _heldCssClass;
}
```

The reason why I retain the CssClass property in a private variable between the method invocations is so prevent side effects from occurring during rendering.  This may be unimportant in your particular code ("is the CssClass property really that important -after- rendering?") but it is always a good idea to prevent or reduce the impact of side effects such as what the code above exhibits by blanking out the property.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the `class` attribute from the `writer` object after rendering the `span` begin tag? I don't know ASP though so I could be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, the writer object doesn't have a "RemoveAttribute" method or the like. And calling writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "") actually creates two CLASS attributes in the INPUT tag; one with "btnOrange" as its value and the other with an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking the base RenderBegin/RenderEnd methods, which themselves will invoke AddAttributesToRender (thereby adding the class attribute), just render the input tag yourself like you are doing with the span....